# How to change color or navigation bar in launchscreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So I am trying to use `launchscreen.storyboard` for my launch screen and I embedded in a navigation bar and a tab bar.

Now my app's navigation bar color and tab bar color is not the default color.

Is there anyway for me to change the launch screen's navigation and tab colors? ( there is no way to add in programmatically since luanchscreen.storyboard is not supposed to have class, right?)

or do I have to use images instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1**

select your navigationController -> click navigation bar --> change barTintColor

**for E.g**

[image]

Comment: Cant believe I didnt find this. I feel so dumb. Thanks alot!!

Comment: @Chris - dont think like bro, every one does not no everything ,